# Custom UIButton not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

After looking through the post on this simple topic I still can not figure out what I've done wrong here.  I am trying to make the buttons loop through the same action in the same viewController.

When the view comes onto the screen the buttons do not click (or at least the NSLog does not write to the console which it does the first time it enters this code.)

```
- (IBAction)answer: (id) sender{
NSLog(@"The Number is: %d\n",qNumber);
qNumber+=1;

UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
[newView setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pink_button.png"];
UIImageView *buttonImageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(23, 294, 72, 37)] autorelease];
[buttonImageView setImage:buttonImage];

UILabel* buttonLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(23, 294, 72, 37)] autorelease];
buttonLabel.text = @"newLow";
buttonLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size: 15.0];
buttonLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
buttonLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor  clearColor];
buttonLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

lowButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; 
[lowButton addSubview:buttonImageView];
[lowButton addSubview:buttonLabel];
[lowButton addTarget:self action:@selector(answer:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[newView addSubview:lowButton];
self.view = newView;
}
```

Thanks for any help you can provide...even if I missed something simple :-)

Latest Updated Code:

```
lowButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; 
[newView addSubview:buttonImageView];
[newView addSubview:buttonLabel];
[lowButton addTarget:self action:@selector(answer:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[newView addSubview:lowButton];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:lowButton];
self.view = newView;
```

Still when the button is pressed it does not enter the action code.

Comment: Please note that you are massively leaking memory. Whenever you add a newly allocated view as a subview, you should release it. Also, you should definitely try to reuse your views by adjusting its subviews or properties rather than creating new ones.

Comment: I imagined it was terrible code.  First shot at doing this, so I expected poor performance out of the gate.  I will work on cleaning it up once I get it to work :-)  Thank you for the great tips to start me down that path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You button needs a frame. You can't tap a frameless button.

```
lowButton.frame = CGRectMake(23, 294, 72, 37);
```

Also, when you add label and image to that button, their frame should have x and y 0.

```
UIImageView *buttonImageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 72, 37)] autorelease];
...
UILabel* buttonLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 72, 37)] autorelease];
...
```

But may I ask why you are adding new UIImageView and UILabel to UIButton when it has it's label and background view properties?

**Edit** here is a cleaned-up code for you:

```
UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];

lowButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; 
[lowButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pink_button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[lowButton setTitle:@"newLow" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[lowButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[lowButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0]];
[lowButton addTarget:self action:@selector(answer:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[newView addSubview:lowButton];
self.view = newView;
```

Notice I also removed `[newView setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];` as it's not needed since it's enabled by default.

Comment: tbh I have had no luck trying to get the text of a lable of a button to change so I have resorted to this.  Also because I barely know what I am doing :-)  The frame worked awesome.  I will work on fixing it all now that I know more about how this all works.  Thanks again!

Comment: I have added a cleaned-up version of your code to my answer above, so take a look. Documentation is a good way to see what properties and methods a class has. You could see UIButton has the methods I used just by looking at it's [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your custom button's subviews are covering the button, so it does not get any clicks.
Try adding all the subviews to `newView` rather than to `lowButton` (including `lowButton` itself) and then call

```
[self.view bringSubViewToFront:lowButton];
```

Comment: Hmm..same result although I thought that was it.

Comment: Leaves the location of the button. Just for testing, try setting the background so you can see where the button is, like `[lowButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];`.